# Symfony validation optional all constraint

Tags: php, validation, symfony

How do I have an `Optional` constraint inside an `All` constraint.

Basically I want to validate that a key exists inside an array, and its value is an array which can include blanks, or any value.

If I omit the key in the `Collection` constraint I get the error:

```
This field was not expected
```

I know I can use the `allowExtraFields`, but I want to validate that the key exists.

I though I would be about to use:

```
$optional = new Constraints\Optional();
$all = new Constraints\All($optional);
```

But that results in:

```
Fatal error: Class 
'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\OptionalValidator' 
not found in 
~\symfony\validator\Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidatorFactory.php 
on line 36
```

Here is the full code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;
$input = [
    'frames' => [
        'header' => [
            'test-header-1',
            'test-header-2',
            '',
        ],
        'content' => [
            'test-content-1',
            'test-content-2',
            '',
        ],
    ],
];
$optional = new Constraints\Optional();
$constraint = new Constraints\Collection([
    'frames' => new Constraints\Collection([
        'header' => new Constraints\All($optional),
        'content' => new Constraints\All($optional),
    ]),
]);
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$violations = $validator->validateValue($input, $constraint);
echo $violations;
```

I also tried:

```
$optional = new Constraints\Optional([
    new Constraints\Type('array'),
]);
$constraint = new Constraints\Collection([
    'frames' => new Constraints\Collection([
        'header' => $optional,
        'content' => $optional,
    ]),
]);
```

But then that does not validate that the key exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just validate that the `header` and `content` items are arrays:

```
$constraint = new Constraints\Collection([
    'frames' => new Constraints\Collection([
        'header' => new Constraints\Type('array'),
        'content' => new Constraints\Type('array'),
    ]),
]);
```